# splunk query to extract multiple fields from single field

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I am new to splunk. My requirement is to display below grid.

```
Method                       Execution Time
IndexController.printHello     519
```

My Event String is below

```
{ "event" : "test", "message" : "OUT: IndexController.printHello - time taken: 519 ms"}
```

I tried with below approach

```
index = "myspluk" | table message | field method, executiontime
```

But it display empty message. I created field extractor but its not working

I want to extract method and execution time from

```
"OUT: IndexController.printHello - time taken: 519 ms"
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would extract what you need with [`rex`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/9.0.1/SearchReference/Rex) and some regex capture groups, from either the `_raw` or the `message` field:

```
index = "myspluk" 
| rex field=_raw "OUT: (?<method>.*?) - time taken: (?<executiontime>\d+) ms" 
| table method executiontime
```

Comment: Thanks Mads Hansen. Its working fine after adding comma in between method and execution time. Thanks for your help. Have a great day

Comment: the comma isn't necessary for the table command

Comment: Yes. Its my bad. Its working without comma also

Answer (score 1):

@[Mads Hansen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14419/mads-hansen)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73940324/4418) will most likely work, but experience shows multiple individual [`rex`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/rex) statements to be safer (ie, they allow for corner cases / data in different sequences, etc):

```
| rex field=message "OUT:\s+(?<method>\S+)"
| rex field=message "taken:\s+(?<executiontime>\d+)"
```

Speed for sequential regular expressions - [9](https://regex101.com/r/O8zCL6/1) & [23](https://regex101.com/r/rf80mH/1) steps, respectively

If you want to use an all-at-once regular expression, because you know the data is always in the same order, [this](https://regex101.com/r/yKiuvj/1) one is simpler and faster (28 vs 82 [steps](https://regex101.com/r/FvMZ1K/1)) than Mads Hansen's:

```
| rex field=message "OUT:\s+(?<method>\S+).+?taken:\s+(?<executiontime>\d+)"
```

Lastly, if you know the order of the `message` field is always the same, you could do [this](https://regex101.com/r/gHC6uH/1), making a multivalue field, and separate it after (I combined two [`eval`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/eval) statements into one line, since they're not dependent upon each other):

```
| rex field=message max_match=0 ":\s+(?<mymvfield>\S+)
| eval method=mvindex(mymvfield,0), executionTime=mvindex(mymvfield,-1)
```